# How to write a Plsql stored procedure

Tags: plsql, procedure

Write a procedure when we give empid as in parameter then it should take emp deptno and display those deptno emp names

Comment: what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

There are various options; here's one of them.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure p_emp (par_empno in emp.empno%type) is
  2    l_row emp%rowtype;
  3  begin
  4    select *
  5      into l_row
  6      from emp
  7      where empno = par_empno;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line(l_row.deptno ||' '|| l_row.ename);
 10  exception
 11    when no_data_found then
 12      dbms_output.put_line('No such employee');
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_emp(7788);
20 SCOTT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_emp(-1);
No such employee

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```